# How to execute a print after else once (without using break)?

Tags: java

I have written some code to simulate hashing.

How can I stop many iterations and print "Not found" once without using `break`?

The main class:

```
public class hash {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        contact[] table = new contact[88]; // Create an object of contact class

        int tablesize = 88;

        int Out = calc_hash("NAME", tablesize);

        table[Out] = new contact();

        table[Out].Name = "AHMED";
        table[Out].phone = 23445677;
        System.out.println(Out);
    }
}
```

My question is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    if (table[i] != null) {
        if (table[i].Name != null) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(table[i].Name);
            System.out.println(table[i].phone);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    } // Here "Not found" is printed with every iteration
}
```

Hash function:

```
public static int calc_hash(String key, int table_size) {
    int i, l = key.length();
    int hash = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        hash += Character.getNumericValue(key.charAt(i));
        hash += (hash << 10);
        hash ^= (hash >> 6);
    }
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);
    if (hash > 0) return hash % table_size;
    else return -hash % table_size;
}
```

Comment: Assign `i = 36` or anything greater than that in your `else` but one thing I am not getting is why not use `break`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `i` to 36 when you are in `else`

```
for  (int i = 0; i < 36  ; i++) 
   {
    if(table[i] !=null ) 
    {
        if (table [i].Name  != null) { 
        System.out.println(i); 
        System.out.println(table [i].Name);
        System.out.println(table [i].phone);}
    }
    else    
        { 
          System.out.println("Not found");
          i=36;
    } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean notFound = false;    
    for  (int i = 0; i < 36  ; i++)
    {
        if(table[i] == null )
        {
           notFound = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (table [i].Name  != null) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(table [i].Name);
            System.out.println(table [i].phone);}
    }

     if(notFound){
      System.out.println("Not found");
     }  // Here "Not found" is printed with every iteration
```

Comment: Hah.  That will work unless the table actually IS full, in which case it prints "Not found" unnecessarily.

Comment: the above code may work as we are printing "Not Found" based on the flag which will be true if any element of table is null.